# How do i get the earliest date and latest date from 5differnt table in sql and populate them into a dropdown form?

Tags: php, sql

i want to create a "generate report" page which shows me statisc regarding what happen within a range of time. How do i get the oldest date from 5 tables and newer date from 5table and populate each different date into 2 dropdown list?

The 5 table are the same.

1 with all the oldest date , and 2 with all the newer date. User can then choose what is the range they required and thus POST the data back to the same page and do a query run with the post?

Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: Providing the table layout would be nice.

Comment: sorry i mean database table...sincere apologies.

Comment: Request still applies. Do you have a timestamp column?

Comment: every table only have a date() type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will most likely be a combination of a "MIN" function and a "UNION" operation

```
SELECT MIN(SOMEDATE) FROM TABLE1
UNION SELECT MIN(SOMEDATE) FROM TABLE2
UNION SELECT MIN(SOMEDATE) FROM TABLE3
```

...

Comment: Hi, this indeed gives me something i wanted the first date() and the last date() , however i have a question how i get the date inbetween? i do a strtotime(-1, "d") or something until i hit the first date?

Comment: Please clarify.  I am not sure what you mean by "inbetween".